# how are viewmodel and foreground services supposed to interact exactly?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

i'm completely new to this sort of thing. in my jetpack compose app i have a media playing functionality, i load and play the media in a foreground service, the service has different states to manage playing state, length, seeking and jumping through the audio track and so on.
the user would interact with the UI buttons and seekbar as they wish, those interactions are sent to the viewmodel which is supposed to do any processing necessary and then pass them to the foreground service to apply the desired changes on the audio track.

the thing is i have no idea how is this supposed to be done correctly, especially when it includes constantly changing states, the audio track current position for example which i need to have it updated constantly and send it to the viewmodel so that the seekbar position on the ui would be updated.

i tried having an interface that contains the functions that the service would implement, and call those function when i want from my viewmodel by binding the service to it. but that isn't working when it comes to updating states..

what should i do?